# Play video using Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an ImageView in my app, users can record video or load from the camera roll. What I need to do if I want to play video in UIImageView.

Her is the code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) // Media is a video
    {
        NSURL* videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        _videoUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[videoUrl absoluteString]];
        [self loadVideo:_videoUrl];


    }

}

- (void)loadVideo:(NSURL*)url
{

    AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate1 = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset1];
    generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
    CGImageRef oneRef = [generate1 copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    UIImage *one = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:oneRef];
    [_imageView setImage:one];
    _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;


}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And I am using below code for play the video, but it's playing video in fullscreen.

```
moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                initWithContentURL:_videoUrl];


moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

I need to play the video, but inside UIImageView. Is it possible?

Comment: You can't play video in UIImageView. You have customise frame of MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: @Lalit's answer might be help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final code should be like this. Your forgot to add frame

```
moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                initWithContentURL:_videoUrl];


moviePlayer.view.frame = _yourImageView.frame;
moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

Comment: check out this link also ... https://vandecybersena.wordpress.com/2015/06/10/play-video-in-ios-app-using-mpmovieplayercontroller-from-url/